# How to change camera parameters (auto exposure, shutter speed, gain)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera, computer-vision, image-capture

I am using Matlab to capture images from 2 Point Grey Cameras (Flea2) and I would like to change some parameters of the cameras such as Auto Exposure, Gain and Shutter Speed. So far I have used these commands:

```
%Creating the two video input of the two cameras
cam1 = videoinput('dcam',1,'Y8_640x480');
cam2 = videoinput('dcam',2,'Y8_640x480');
%get devices properties
src1 = getselectedsource(cam1);
src2 = getselectedsource(cam2);
%define and set parameters to be changed
properties = {'AutoExposureAbsolute','AutoExposureControl', 'AutoExposureMode', 'GainAbsolute', 'GainControl', 'GainMode','ShutterAbsolute','ShutterControl', 'ShutterMode'};
values = {0,'absolute', 'manual', 0,'absolute', 'manual', 0, 'manual', 5e-06, 'absolute', 'manual'};
set(src1, properties, values)
set(src2, properties, values)
```

So, if I display src1 and src2 variables the above properties has been modified but when I preview the cameras nothing has changed.

While using always the same syntax for changing the frame rate I am successful.

Comment: I assume you hit a bug in the driver. I would try it with some other library (opencv?) and check if the same error exists. If so you can be sure the camera manufacturer caused the issue.

Comment: did you ask Point Grey support yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem installing the [Image Acquisition Toolbox Support Package for Point Grey Hardware](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45178-image-acquisition-toolbox-support-package-for-point-grey-hardware). 
Then, you need to change the adapter type using the Point Grey driver:

`cam = videoinput('pointgrey',1,'Mono8_640x480');`

Now, you can set normally the properties of the cameras (auto exposure, shutter speed, gain) through Matlab. For example, if you want so set a specific value of the Shutter:

```
src = getselectedsource(cam);
set(src, 'Shutter', value)
```

Concerning my question I suppose that the device specific properties of Point Grey cameras cannot be edited directly through MATLAB with the *dcam* driver, but in order to modify such properties you need to use the Matlab support package for Point Grey Hardware.